# How to update datasource array (without sections) using UITableView indexPath (with sections)?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have an original array of items, retrieved from the database:

```
var items = [Item]()
```

which contains:

1. Fruit, Apple, Red, 1
2. Fruit, Orange, Orange, 2
3. Vegetable, Lettuce, Green, 1
4. Drink, Milk, White, 1

To display this list in a UITableView grouped by sections, I'm generating the following structure:

```
struct Section {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionItems : [Item]!
}

var sections : [Section]!
```

And with the sections array, I can display my UITableView properly. If I need to change the quantity of an item, I can easily change the item in the **sections** array, accessing the data through the indexpath's section and row.

**The problem:**

However, I can not figure out how to change the original data (the list of 4 items), which is the one I need to use to save in the database. The indexpath information tells me nothing about which index in the **items** array I need to access in order to perform the changes.

**Solutions?**

I'm thinking about two solutions, neither of which seem too good:

1. Rebuilding the original list by iterating through "sections". Sounds like a lot of unnecessary iterations, considering I could just simply access the item through an index.
2. Create an additional property to each item that keeps its index position in the original array. This one looks very messy, though.

How would you guys and girls go about it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Option 1 is simple and is only one easy iteration.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for commenting! I agree, I only worry if that would create room for inconsistencies. By sticking to one original array and performing only the necessary changes on that array, it seems to be a safer approach considering data handling and computing efficiency. But yeah, option 1 does seem like the simplest solution.

Comment: I wouldn't even keep the original array. It is pretty trivial to reconstruct it from your `sections` array whenever you need it.